# Easy mainFrame/Windows not working! JAVA

Tags: java, swing

Hey guys this should be really easy to fix. But I am not sure what the error is.

code is at this link http://pastebin.com/qvFE8EJU

Comment: whats the error in this?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: `//startScreen a = new startScreen();` ... you don't think this is a problem?

Comment: Change `mainPanel.setVisible(true);` to `mainFrame.setVisible(true);`.  I'd also move `setDefaultCloseOperation` to before `setVisible`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as Constructor remains commented out, not showing anything is correct behaviour.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            startScreen a = new startScreen();
    }
```

Try it this way (and edit your post to include source)

As MadProgrammer mentioned - you need to make the Frame visible to make all the Components within visible:

```
            // REPLACE THIS mainPanel.setVisible(true);
            mainFrame.setVisible (true); //WITH THAT
```

Comment: Swing components are visible by default show the use of `mainPanel.setVisible` is pointless

Comment: Thank you guys a lot. I feel so dumb.